# Why is moksha difficult to attain?

Tags: moksha

Why is moksha difficult to attain? Why can't it be easy? What is the reason for the existence of moksha? Does it exist because maya exists? If yes, wouldn't that mean moksha has no existence out of maya?

Comment: Moksha literally means tearing away. Tearing away from what? From suffering created by our ego. To remove suffering, we must free ourselves from selfishness and anger resulting from our self obsession.

Comment: moksha requires shadana. .1. Atma shakshathkara 2. Paramatma shakshathkara.. Most of the philosophy emphasis only atma shakshathkara only because for them only Atma exists. that atma is paramatma.. Guided by wrong philosophies the world is confused.. And to do the point 2. is very very difficult because God had to appear and speak to you just like person in front of you.. So moksha is very difficult, because its only the mercy of lord can get..

Comment: The subject matter is SPIRITUALITY explaining of which it is difficult, many a time, to find scriptural base.  We can quote the statements of saints, which were made out of their personal experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because senses are out-going and hence we experience only outer objects and not the inner self.

[Katha Upanishad 2.1.1](http://shankaracharya.org/katha_upanishad.php):

> 1     Yama said: The self-existent Supreme Lord inflicted an injury upon the sense-organs in creating them **with outgoing tendencies**; therefore a man perceives only outer objects with them and not the inner Self. But a calm person, wishing for Immortality, beholds the inner Self with his eyes closed.

That's why mind is constantly engaged in perceiving outer objects and one doesn't differentiate between Atma (the self) and Anatma (non-self) due to lake of knowledge of true self.

As explained in [Vivekachudamani](http://www.shastras.com/adi-sankara/vivekachudamani/):

> 145. Of the tree of Samsara ignorance is the seed, the identification with the body is its sprout, attachment its tender leaves, work its water, the body its trunk, the vital forces its branches, the organs its twigs, the sense-objects its flowers, various miseries due to diverse works are its fruits, and the individual soul is the bird on it.
> 146. This bondage can be destroyed neither by weapons nor by wind, nor by fire, nor by millions of acts - by nothing except the wonderful sword of knowledge that comes of discrimination, sharpened by the grace of the Lord.

Hence, the knowledge of discrimination between the self and non-self is essential to be realized and the outward tendencies of senses are first obstacles in it. This is another reason why most of people choose pleasurable over preferable as told in first two verses of Katha Upanishad 1.2.

Regarding Maya, yes, definitely it is responsible for bondage and it's also believed difficult to overcome the power of Maya as said by Lord Krishna in Bhagavad Gita:

> 7.14 Since this divine Maya of Mine which is constituted by the gunas is difficult to cross over, (therefore) those who take refuge in Me alone cross over this Maya.

Maya has two powers; the projection power and the veiling power which creates resistance from gaining true knowledge. But after attaining Jnana, it doesn't hold more as per Advaita Vedanta.

So, the true knowledge of self i.e Jnana and grace of god i.e Bhakti are essential to attain Moksha as decleared in [Mundaka Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-atharva-veda/mundaka-upanishad/):

> III-ii-3: This Self is not attained through study, nor through the
> intellect, nor through much hearing. The very Self which this one (i.e.
> the aspirant) seeks is attainable through that fact of seeking; this
> Self of his reveals Its own nature.

Though most of people tends to say or show that they extremely believe in god but they don't, illustrated by Swami Vivekananda, quoting from [Complete Works / Volume 1 / Lectures and Discourses / Steps to Realization](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/lectures_and_discourses/steps_to_realisation.htm):

> A great sage once told me that not one in twenty millions in this world believed in God. I asked him why, and he told me, "Suppose there is a thief in this room, and he gets to know that there is a mass of gold in the next room, and only a very thin partition between the two rooms; what will be the condition of that thief?" I answered, "He will not be able to sleep at all; his brain will be actively thinking of some means of getting at the gold, and he will think of nothing else." Then he replied, "Do you believe that a man could believe in God and not go mad to get him? If a man sincerely believes that there is that immense, infinite mine of Bliss, and that It can be reached, would not that man go mad in his struggle to reach it ?"

Talking about other points:

> **Q.** What is the reason for the existence of moksha? If yes, wouldn't that mean moksha has no existence out of maya?

More or less yes, Bondage and Moksha are due to the work of mind only. "Mind is the only cause of bondage and liberation" - [Maitrayini Upanishad](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-sama-veda/maitrayani-upanishad/) 4.3.11. This is told straight forwardly by Gaudapada in his [karika on Mandukya Upanishad 2.32](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya/d/doc143663.html) "There is no dissolution, no birth, none in bondage, none aspiring for wisdom, no seeker of liberation and none liberated. This is the absolute truth."

---

Briefly, the lack of {Jijnasa of knowing the true self and extreme faith in the self} makes it difficult to attain Jnana, the true self and hence Moksha.

Comment: I think the VivekChudamani verses no. in your answer are not correct . The verse 145 should be verse 147 and verse 146 should be 149( I am looking at gita press version though) . BTW great and extensive answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Right. This differs from Gitapress version. Actually all the online version we find are identical in number of verses so, I cite one of them.

Comment: Ok :- ) , i will try to add sanskrit shlokas afterwards to all.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes, I also like Sanskrit Shlokas to be added but I skipped looking at length of answer.